# How can I get civi fields with multiple options to offer the "multiple field setting" in the way that drupal fields do?

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

I know the simple answer is "add this functionality to the civi views module" but it has been mentioned in other tickets but the fact that this could be possible but isn't doesn't seem to have been addressed directly.

My testing suggests CiviCRM Entity does not add this currently either. Below is a screenshot for a drupal 'content' based view that has a field that is a multiselect to show what is offered for such fields in the View.

[image]

Comment: Pete, not sure I understand quite what the 'multiple field setting' is that you're referring to.  Could you give an example?

Comment: Fair point. added now.